# Chaining modals in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following template which have 4 modal like (just a difference in id):

```
<div id="modal_1">
    <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>I'm a modal 1!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app.js looks like:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $cookieStore, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {
     if(!$cookieStore.get('abc')){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
  }
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

`

My requirement:

I wish to show 4 modals (one after the other when the user clicks "ok") if a specific cookie is not available and the user has not "cancelled" any of the other previous modals.

But I am not able to chain the modals.

How do I chain the modals so the previous modal opens another modal until a condition is not met?

Comment: a new modal instead of the last one, or a new modal on top of the last one?

Comment: Code shown is the code directly from the modal documents demo. It doesn't show any attempt to open a different modal. Create a factory function around the modal initialization code and pass in the step information so you can change template and logic in result callback

Comment: you can chain several modals by using promises `$q`. If the user clicks OK you execute a `resolve` and the app will open the next modal. If teh user clicks Cancel you execute a `reject` and close all Modals.

Comment: I think It's better to use a wizard.Something like this: https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a utility function to reduce typing:

```
function showModal(templateUrl){
   return $modal.open({
      templateUrl: templateUrl,
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      };
   }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
showModal('template1.html')
   .then(function(selectedItemFromTemplate1){
      return showModal('template2.html');
   })
   .then(function(selectedItemFromTemplate2){
      return showModal('template3.html');
   })
   .then(function(selectedItemFromTemplate3){
      return showModal('template4.html');
   })
   .catch(function(reason){
      console.log('did not go through all steps because ' + reason);
   })
   .then(function(selectedItemFromTemplate4){
      console.log('finished');
   });
```

Comment: Can't he simply call $scope.open() IF(cookie != available) inside modalInstance.result ?

Comment: I described how he could chain the modals. The sample code above can of course be adapted to whatever business logic he wants to include. He could even throw an exception to cancel the chaining at any time.